# How do I a find a formula of a function with given vertical and horizontal asymptotes?

Tags: calculus

How do I a find a function that has vertical asymptotes $x$ = $7$ and $x$ = $9$ and horizontal asymptote $y$ = $7$ ?

Comment: Vertical asymptotes come in the form of $\frac{1}{x - x_0}$ where $x_0$ is a vertical asymptote.  All you need for a horizontal asymptote $f(x) + y_0$ where $f(x)$ tends towards $0$ and the horizontal asymptote is $y_0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general if those are the only requirements, you can take a [rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function),

$$f(x) = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$

where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials. Since you need 2 vertical asymptotes, you can take Q(x) = (x-7)(x-9) (in general just take a polynomial where the vertical asymptotes are the roots). Now, as for the horizontal asymptote, you can easily prove that if $deg(P) = deg(Q)$ and the leading coefficients for $P$ and $Q$ are $p$ and $q$ respectively,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = \frac{p}{q}$$

So in this example,

$f(x) := \frac{7x^2}{(x-7)(x-9)}$

is a function that does what you want.